# How can we catch recent activity of user in our web page using facebook open graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I got an issue in my project and i need your help.

I want to catch recent activity of user on my web-page, for eg: suppose if user clicks on my url and afterwards clicked on some hyperlink to download a file.  So here user has done two activities - first clicked on hyperlink and second downloaded an image.

Basically I want to capture this activity of the user (ie activity done by user on my website) and post it on the user's "Recent Activity" section on his Facebook profile. Is it posible to do this using Facebook open graph API? I am new to it, any suggestion will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Open Graph Follows will allow you to post recent activity, specifically the section on "Notifications and Stories for Follow Activity".  The person will have to be following you and install your app.  But then you can post "stories" such as "Mark drank an iced tea".  Make sure you tell Facebook you need the "publish_actions" permission for your app.

As for *how* to implement this, use ajax calls back to a PHP script that will post these for you.

Documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/follows/)